# How to take a full length screenshot of the iPhone Messages app?

Tags: ios, iphone

How can we do a "full page" (full length, from first message to the last message) screenshot?

For example, this should be the resulting image:

[image]

It's just **one** unified image, not multiple screenshots.

Is there a way to do this easily?

(Taking multiple screenshots and merging them together with Photoshop like what we have above is **not** a real solution.)

Comment: I assume you're talking of a 'webpage screenshot' inside safari?

Comment: @gentmatt No I wanted to screenshot a long list of messages in Messaging app.

Comment: There's a thread on Quora too: https://www.quora.com/How-does-Damn-You-Autocorrect-take-long-iPhone-screenshots

Answer (score 10):

[Stich It!](https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/id554594252?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) is the App you're looking for I believe.

Answer (score 4):

There is no other way without venturing into the adventures of jailbreaking your phone, and even in doing that I make no promises that something to save your conversation exists already. The ability to view the output of Messages.app is otherwise completely protected in a normal iPhone software setup, except to a full screen screenshot. You will have to take a series of screenshots, and stitch them together via photo editing software.

There may be stitching apps on the iPhone that can do the editing part appropriately (some kind of panorama software?), but you will still have to take screenfuls of screenshots manually.

Answer (score 0):

[Drumroll please....]

This can be accomplished by using Quicktime to create a "Movie Recording"

http://www.apptamin.com/blog/capture-iphone-ipad-screen-video/

Comment: That's a video, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this app, it stitches your screenshots into one long image 
“Tailor - Screenshot Stitching”

Comment: It helps if you provide links to off-site resources you reference in your answer.